# React Redux, load data from the API on first page load ONLY. Render component once data is loaded

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, create-react-app

I am DEFINITELY doing something wrong at the core of my app.

I think its *where* I am making a request to my API. I'm also not happy with the firstLoad flagging to tell the app to call the API.

I am using React/Redux - building from this boiler plate https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app-redux.

It uses mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps and connect to glue everything together.

So I have a component called "Shop"

```
// only true when user first visits url OR presses F5 to refresh. 
// Its conveniently false when page rerenders
var firstLoad = true; 
const Shop = ({ stateProps, dispatchProps }) => {
  if(firstLoad) {
    firstLoad = false;
    // dispatchProps contains a method called changeState that will update state.shops to the result from the API. It will also set state.loading to true while calling and false when finished.
    // Note, I am not modifying state directly. The dispatchProps wraps the action that does so
    server.GetShops({url: "api/shops", updateField:"shops", loading:true, token:"abc-xyz"}, dispatchProps);
  }

  if(stateProps.loading) {
    return (
      <div>loading...</div>
    );
  }

  var shopUrl = window.location.href; // extract the part of the url after the domain

  var selectedShop = stateProps.shops.find(s => {
      return s.url === shopUrl;
  });

  if(!selectedShop) {
    window.location.href = "/";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {selectedShop.welcomeMessage}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem im having is I have to refresh TWICE to see when the welcomeMessage is changed.

So if its originally "hello world" from the database and I change it to "hello UK" in the database.

When I refresh the page, i expect the app to fetch data and display loading.
When it finished fetching data, a re-render occurs and it should show Hello UK in the welcome message.

However this doesn't happen until the second page refresh.

Does what I described make sense to anyone?

Comment: why dont you use useEffect or lifecycle methods like componentDidMount

Comment: Honestly, with the create-react-app-redux template folder structure, I haven't figured that out yet, it feels like a different beast to just using react as a lib. I dont know how that would work with pipeline supplied for configuration of the store and thunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not making any change based on the value of `selectedShop`
you should keep the value of selectedShop in a local state variable

```
const [ selectedShop , setSelectedShop ] = useState({});
```

then whenever the value is changed from api call update the local state value

```
useEffect( () => {

  var selectedShop = stateProps.shops.find(s => {
      return s.url === shopUrl;
  });

   setSelectedShop(selectedShop);

} , [stateProps.shops])
```

now when the value changes in stateProps it will update the local state value and trigger a re render .

Comment: still working on it. I think you are onto something :))

Comment: thanks. useEffect really helped me out. I have never used that before.

Comment: Laughing at my past self 2 years later!!!